# ng-repeat shows nothing with init angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<body ng-app>
    <div class="container" ng-init="nameList=['Adam','Rain','John',King]" ng-model="nameList">
        <input type="text" ng-model="nameText" />
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="name in nameList | filter:nameText | orderBy:'name'">{{name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

no idea what's wrong with my code, what I want to do is to filter out some names with the input.. like I enter "A", it display only "Adam"..

Comment: This is working for me http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/R4WGp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nameList=['Adam','Rain','John',King]
```

Should be:

```
nameList=['Adam','Rain','John','King']
```

**UPDATE**

Oh, sorry. You mean's match the first words of the item?
Shoule add a custom filter for it:

```
angular.module("app", [])
.filter("matchfirst", function() {
  return function(input, filter) {
      if (!input) return input;
      if (!filter) return input;
    var result=[]
    filter=filter.toLowerCase()
    for (i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        if (input[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(filter)==0) {
            result.push(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
  }
});
```

Edit HTML:

```
<body ng-app='app'>
    <div class="container" ng-init="nameList=['Adam','Rain','John','King']" ng-model="nameList">
        <input type="text" ng-model="nameText" />
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="name in nameList | matchfirst:nameText | orderBy:'name'">{{name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

This works good: http://jsfiddle.net/R4WGp/1/

Comment: At least yes but it doesn't resolve the initial problem.

Answer (score 1):

It will work with right data initialization:

```
<body ng-app>
    <div class="container" ng-init="nameList=[{name:'Adam'},{name:'Rain'},{name:'John'},{name:'King'},{name:'Adbm'}]" ng-model="nameList">
        <input type="text" ng-model="nameText" />
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="n in nameList | filter:nameText | orderBy:'name':false">{{n.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

You were calling the "name" but this attribute doesn't exist in your list. Then you can order by name (ASC) or -name (DESC) or use the reverse boolean field true or false.